# Accessing variables from javascript in modal (noob)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get modelname to show up in the modal. In other words, how do I properly pass the variable from javascript to my modal?

I have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".cadlib", function () {
     var modelname = $('#modelname').text();
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

And a modal dialog:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">My Modal</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
Here's all the info you would want to know about {{modelname}} 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a placeholder element that you can target - replace `{{modelname}}` with something like `<span id="modelnameplaceholder"></span>`. Then, you can do something like:

```
$('#modelnameplaceholder').replaceWith(modelname);
```

**Reference**: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

**Example jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/G82mk/

Comment: You rock! :-) In general, is that best practices for passing variables from javascript back into a template?

Comment: @user1328021 It's probably the simplest thing to learn. There are JavaScript templating engines that work more like what you were trying to do, but I have not had an opportunity to sit down and learn them, so I can't really give you any examples.

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
var modelname = $('#modelname').text();
```

Add this:

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').html($('#myModal .modal-body').html().replace('{{modelname}}', modelname));
```

Comment: I think it's because in the HTML you provided there is no element with the ID '#modelname' so the var modelname is the empty string.